# How to resolve Undefined and Nan?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup

I'm building an Chrome extension and I encountered following error in my popup.
[image]

I clearly defined 'total' variable and storing in it a value from local storage.But why am I 
getting such an error?

**What I'm trying to do:**

1)I'm storing total variable in local storage and access it from popup.js.
2)Then modify `<p>` elements in popup.html

**Here is popup.html and popup.js:**

**popup.js:**

```
var total,percentage;

chrome.storage.local.get('myVariable', function (items) { 
total = (items.myVariable);
});



percentage = total/7.25;

document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
document.getElementById("percentage").innerHTML = percentage;
```

**popup.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
  <head>
  <title>Popup page</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <form name="F1" method="POST">
        TOTAL  : <p id="total"></p>
    PERCENTAGE : <p id="percentage"></p>    
  </form>

  <script src="popup.js">

  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Snippet from my contentscript.js**

```
 chrome.storage.local.set({
         'myVariable': total;
        });
 chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
     greeting: "myAction"
 });
```

**In background.js I've got this :**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.greeting == "myAction") {
        collectData();
    }
 });
```

Should we add a listener to popup.js before accessing local storage. I added and checked but 
I'm getting the same result.
What's wrong with this code?
How can accomplish what I'm set to do?

**Local storage of my extension:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `chrome.storage.local.get` callback is executed asynchronously so total doesn't get defined until after you try to use it. If instead move the rest of the script into the callback it should work.

```
var total,percentage;

chrome.storage.local.get('myVariable', function (items) { 
    total = (items.myVariable);

    percentage = total/7.25;

    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
    document.getElementById("percentage").innerHTML = percentage;
});
```

Comment: I tried as suggested  but it didn't work buddy. console.logs.items() is showing 'undefined' for the stored variable.I've added a screenshot of my local storage, in which var is not stored.How can I solve this plz?

Answer (score 1):

Two main errors:
1) just doing var x is a no-op in javascript, you must assign it a value.
2) even if you fix that you have a bigger bug. Storage is async so the line after 'get' is executed before you have the get result.

Comment: how can I fix the issue then?

Comment: put breakpoints and debug it. the answer above mine says the same and has a working sample